# Get specific value from Localstorage key and populate div

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a key in localStorage and I want to get specific value and populate an element with it.

Example:

```
<div id="results"></div>

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('customer');

customer = {
    "fullname": "John Doe",
    "firstname": "John"
};
```

This of course outputs the full key. How do I retrieve and display just the value of `fullname` ?

Comment: I assume that the object is stored as a JSON string, given that localStorage can only contain strings. As such, you can run it through `JSON.parse()` before accessing the properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the string value and get the key you need:

```
var customer = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customer'));
var fullname = customer.fullname;
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = fullname;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect and is very clear.